# Benchmarking conditional assignments to an Array in Julia

Tags: arrays, performance, julia

I'm new to Julia and I was testing my understanding by the following benchmarks of three equivalent ways to set all elements of an Array smaller than `0.5` to `0.`:

```
using BenchmarkTools

function test!(A)
    @btime begin # method 1
        mask = $A .< 0.5
        $A[mask] .= 0.
    end
    @btime begin # method 2
        $A[$A .< 0.5] .= 0.
    end
    @btime begin # method 3
        @inbounds begin
            for i in eachindex($A)
                if $A[i] < 0.5
                    $A[i] = 0.
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
n = 1000
test!(rand(n,n))
```

This outputs

```
  1.612 ms (13 allocations: 3.94 MiB)
  1.619 ms (13 allocations: 3.94 MiB)
  4.215 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Based on what I have read about Julia until now I have several questions:

1. Why is method 3 the slowest? I'd expect it to be the fastest, since it avoids any heap allocations. I tried to look at the LLVM/native code output but that went over my head.
2. Why are method 1 and 2 equally fast? For me method 1 is the "Python/Numpy method", where allocating an intermediate array for storing the mask is a typical (unwanted) byproduct of vectorized Numpy programming. I had expected Julia to optimize method 2 into method 3 through the `.` operator.
3. The expected behavior is to have no allocations and near-C fast performance, preferably without an explicit for-loop. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Methods 1 and 2 are identical, they both create a temporary array for the mask. If you want 'fused' broadcasting, you also have to dot the indexing part, and that isn't possible in Julia (yet, at least). You could try to explicitly use the `setindex!` function.

Comment: OK, thanks. I also found the `replace!` function, which is as fast as @Oscar Smith's `f3(A)` below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benchmark is kind of weird. If you instead define 3 functions like so,

```
function f1(A)
       mask = A .< .5
       A[mask] .= 0
end
function f2(A)
    A[A .< .5] .= 0.
end
function f3(A)
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(A)
        if A[i] < .5
            A[i] = 0.
        end
    end
end
```

and `@btime` them, I get that `f3` is about 2x faster.

Comment: Indeed, this produces the expected behavior for method 3. Is this because of the use of `$A` in my test function?

Comment: I think (but don't know that the problem is the way you are repeatedly interpolating prevents Julia from knowing that all your `A`'s are the same